# Nothing shows up with WHERE clause mySQL

Tags: php, mysql, database, search, where-clause

I'm trying to put through a basic search through my Database based on a user entry, and I could not get it to work, so I'm doing a hard coded search just so I can get it to work... and I can't. My code is as follows:

```
<?php

    $db_connection = mysqli_connect("HOST", "USERNAME", "PASSWORD", "DATABASE");

    if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }

    $data = mysql_query($db_connection, "SELECT * FROM card_collection WHERE ID='1207409700'");
    while( $card = mysql_fetch_array( $data ) ) {
            echo $card['Name'], '<br />';   
            }

    mysql_close();

?>
```

I've double checked spelling for everything linked to the database. The ID I'm basing my search from is the first item in my database.

Comment: whats the data type on the id field?

Comment: Typically, the ID is an integer.  So try taking the quotes off from around the ID number.

Comment: In MySql field names are case sensitive, did you check if the field name is actually ID and the table name is card_collection?

Comment: Try make use of myqlli_XX  methods see [mysqli_connect][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17754315/nothing-shows-up-with-where-clause-mysql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the `mysqli_connect` to database and then you are using the `mysql_query` to execute the query it should be `mysqli_query`

You code should be:

```
$data = mysqli_query($db_connection, "SELECT * FROM card_collection WHERE ID='1207409700'");
while( $card = mysqli_fetch_array( $data ) ) {
        echo $card['Name'], '<br />';   
        }

mysqli_close();
```

Replace the `mysql` with the `mysqli`. This may be your problem.

Comment: Thanks, I'm still learning all this and it's easy to miss a letter!

Comment: @JonathanOwenChute Happy to help you. this happens. just mark the answer as accepted. this will be reward to me.

Comment: @BrokenHeartღ I will once I can (need to wait 5 minutes)

Comment: @echo_Me yah, you are right dear... I have lost her. she is so beautiful .... I cann't explain it. :(

Comment: there is million beautiful ,dont fix your heart on one , you can fix it if you live with her and married , but if she gone , its done , reinstall new windows now :)

Comment: @echo_Me friend, I also want to that. that's why I spend my whole time here. but you if feel confert with someone then they will be your life.

Comment: no one can make your life , its you who make your life. im confort with 1000 people. you just hurt yourself. ok good luck and take care of your heart.

Answer (score 2):

I personally use PDO and not mysqli, but is the problem perhaps that you use mysql_query and mysql_fetch_array, instead of mysqli_query and mysqli_fetch_array? Note the missing i

Edit: dangit, beat to the punch :)

Answer (score -1):

```
    <?php

        $db_connect = mysqli_connect("host", "user", "pass", "db");

        if($db_connect){ 
        $data = mysqli_query($db_connection, "SELECT * FROM card_collection WHERE ID='1207409700'");}
else {"Not Connected to db";}
        while( $card = mysqli_fetch_array( $data ) ) {
                echo $card['Name'], '<br />';   
                }

        mysqli_close();

    ?>
```

Comment: Once you wrote 'mysql' and then you wrote 'mysqli', it doesn't work that way